# Inserting JSON output into Database every X minutes?

Tags: php, sql, cron

Although I know how to do this, the way I'm thinking just doesn't seem "the best", using PHP.

I have an API (locally) which produces a JSON output with a lot of data which I want in my database, however I'd only like to update every 5 or so minutes.

The way I'd do this is:

1. Parse JSON output
2. Check response (status = true/false)
3. If true, loop through the JSON and insert it into the database
4. Use a cron job to execute it whenever I want

However I see some problems with this.

- What would stop someone from loading that page in their browser and updating it?
- How do I handle errors or get notified when the JSON status output is false?
- Surely running an insert query for every JSON "loop" is inefficient?

I'm open to all options here - looking for the most effective/secure/reusable option.... which doesn't have to be PHP but I've most experience with it.

Answer (score 0):

Is it entirely necessary for the api file (which returns your JSON) to reside within the `public_html` directory? Same goes for the files which interact with this file.
You could prevent access to the files with a `.htaccess` rewrite rule (or something similar, if you're not using Apache).

Yes running an `insert` every loop is inefficient. You could create larger batch inserts with the `INSERT INTO ... VALUES` syntax. If your dataset is small you could just do one big `insert`.